# How to extract text smileys from a string in android

Tags: android, emoticons

I am working on an android application in which I want to convert all keyboard types smileys into emoji icons.

I am already using this library https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon to show Emoticons in my app.

Now, I want to convert the smileys which users will type using keyboard into emoticons.

Ex: If user type the string Hello World :) :P: 
 1. Then I need to first extract these smiley symbols and for that I need a regex pattern which will extract all these types of symbols from a string. 
 2. I need to find Unicode of these symbols and then convert these symbols in emoticons using the above library.

Please help me, so that I can proceed here.

Answer (score 1):

this lib is using `ImageSpan`s and `SpannableStringBuilder` like here:
[EmojiconTextView](https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon/blob/master/lib/src/github/ankushsachdeva/emojicon/EmojiconTextView.java)

```
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
    EmojiconHandler.addEmojis(getContext(), builder, mEmojiconSize, mTextStart, mTextLength);
    super.setText(builder, type);
}
```

you can always remove spans from current `SpannableStringBuilder` and get plain text

if you want to set spans "in fly" just use `TextWatcher` for your `EditText`, smth like here: [EmojiconEditText](https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon/blob/master/lib/src/github/ankushsachdeva/emojicon/EmojiconEditText.java)

```
protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
    EmojiconHandler.addEmojis(getContext(), getText(), mEmojiconSize);
}
```

this lib seems to do all work for you, just use `View`s from lib (`Emojicon` prefix) instead usual ones, e.g.

```
<ankushsachdeva.emojicon.EmojiconTextView
        android:id="@+id/emojicon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        emojicon:emojiconSize="24dip"
        android:gravity="center"/>
```

instead `EditText` in XML layout files

Comment: This is fine, I have already implemented Emoji Keyboard in my application using this library, but I want to convert simple text smileys also in Emoticons. 
I need a regex pattern to extract the text smileys from a string, can someone please help me here.

Thanks :)

Comment: How can I extract symbols like :) or :P :d from a string. I need a pattern to detect all these types of symbols from a string.